# upload xml file to ftp server via ax2012

Tags: ftp, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, ftpwebrequest

i'm looking for to connect to ftp via dynamics ax 2012 and upload file xml on the ftp server, i have do that job for test , but i can 't connect to ftp  i get this error `Impossible de créer l'objet 'CLRObject'`

```
static void uploadTestFile(Args _args) {
   System.Object ftpo;
   System.Object ftpResponse;
   System.Net.FtpWebRequest request;
   System.IO.StreamReader reader;
   System.IO.Stream requestStream;
   System.Byte[] bytes;
   System.Net.NetworkCredential credential;
   System.String xmlContent;
   System.Text.Encoding utf8;
   System.Net.FtpWebResponse response;
   ;
   // Read file
   reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("ftp://net.sites.com/user/test.xml");
   utf8 = System.Text.Encoding::get_UTF8();
   bytes = utf8.GetBytes( reader.ReadToEnd() );
   reader.Close();
   // little workaround to get around the casting in .NET
   ftpo = System.Net.WebRequest::Create("ftp://net.sites.com/user/test.xml");
   request = ftpo;

   credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("login","pass");
   request.set_Credentials(credential);
   request.set_ContentLength(bytes.get_Length());
   request.set_Method("STOR");
   // "Bypass" a HTTP Proxy (FTP transfer through a proxy causes an exception)
   // request.set_Proxy( System.Net.GlobalProxySelection::GetEmptyWebProxy() );
   requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
   requestStream.Write(bytes,0,bytes.get_Length());
   requestStream.Close();

   ftpResponse = request.GetResponse();
   response = ftpResponse;
   info(response.get_StatusDescription());
}
```

Comment: Where the error occurs?
StreamReader does not support *ftp://* protocol. You must download the file also with the [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Net.FtpWebRequest)

Comment: Thank you for replay , i have fixec that and i can read end upload to ftp ,  now i d't know how can i delete file from ftp server

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [this blog](http://axandhellisfunafterall.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/ftpwebrequest-class.html)

> Once more [axaptapedia.com](http://www.axaptapedia.com/FtpWebRequest) saves the day. This time pointing us to the [FtpWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) in the .NET framework inside Dynamics AX. The Axaptapedia page is complete except for one wafer-thin omission... Exception handling.

Comparing your code with that on the blog I'd say that it does not apply for [InteropPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa605505(v=ax.50).aspx)?  Also the blog mentiones executing on the server, which may avoid other potential errors such as not having [ftp.exe](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm) installed on the system...  You HAVE checked that an FTP client exists on the machine, right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `StreamReader` initialisation:

```
reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("ftp://net.sites.com/user/test.xml");
```

If the source file is coming from FTP, you can rewrite this section as follows:

```
System.IO.Stream responseStream;

ftpo = System.Net.WebRequest::Create("ftp://net.sites.com/user/testFrom.xml");
request = ftpo;

credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("login","pass");
request.set_Credentials(credential);
request.set_Method("RETR");

response = request.GetResponse();
responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream);
```